# com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.type.ClassTypeImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.mirror.type.AnnotationType

Tags: java, maven

Anyone know what could be causing the subject error?  I found another post

[Enunciate Issue = Assembling the enunciate app. com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.type.ClassTypeImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.mirror.type.AnnotationType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669016/enunciate-issue-assembling-the-enunciate-app-com-sun-tools-apt-mirror-type-cl)

about removing jackson exclusions from dependency but I don't have any of those.

I started getting this error after finally getting past a related one:
[maven doesn't find class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704449/maven-doesnt-find-class/33768201#33768201)

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to Java 7 and the error went away.  The enunciate plugin I was using was 1.25 which does not work with Java 8.